# zsh prompt displaying >R alongside current git branch

Tags: git, zsh

I use `zsh` and I recently started seeing this `master >R` instead of just `master`.

git status below;

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'upstream/master'.
Last command done (1 command done):
   edit d36ecbb cfn II
No commands remaining.
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'DEV-87' on '7b06369'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `git status` say? I'm guessing you're in the middle of a rebase operation.

Comment: Like I guessed, you're in the middle of a rebase. You can abort it with `git rebase --abort`. The next question is, why did you not realize you were performing a rebase? Git is not something to idly issue commands to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, per your "screenshot" it looks like you are rebasing and thus get a `>R` marker...

If you want to abort the rebase, type `git rebase --abort`.